# Initialize viewmodel and refresh after ajax seach results are back

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

How do I initialize the viewModel first time the page is loaded?

The refresh from Ajax call works and loads the data correctly after the ajax call but on the first load the page does not know the model.

```
    var viewModel = {};
         $("#searchButton").click(function () {
                    var tc= $("#tc").val();
                    var y= $("#y").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "Search/?t=" + tc+ "&y=" + y,
                        type:'GET',
                        dataType: 'json',
                                        success: function (result) {
                            viewModel = new TourViewModel(result);
                            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
                        }
                    });
                });

                function TourViewModel(data) {
                    var self = this;
                    var tourMapping = {};

                    self.selectedItem = ko.observable("");
                    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("");
                    self.saveMe = function () {
                                                            viewModel.selectedItem(this);
                        self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.selectedItem), null, 2));
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "SaveTour",
                            data: ko.toJSON({ tour:ko.toJS(self.selectedItem) }),
                            type: "post",
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            success: function (result)
                                { alert(result) }
                        });

                    }

                    selectItem = function () {
                        self.selectedItem(this);
                    }

                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, tourMapping, self);


                };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly basic example. Do your ajax call then initialize the model using the results.

```js
var ViewModel = function(r) {
  var self = this;
  this.Beers = ko.observableArray(r.map(function(beer) {
    return new BeersModel(beer);
  }));
  this.RefreshBeer = function() {
    self.Beers([]);
    GetBeer()
      .then(function(response) {
        self.Beers(response.map(function(beer) {
          return new BeersModel(beer);
        }))
      });
  }
}

var BeersModel = function(r) {
  this.name = r.name;
}

var GetBeer = function() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers',
    method: 'GET'
  })
}

// Do init ajax stuff, and load viewModel
GetBeer()
  .then(function(response) {
    var model = new ViewModel(response);
    ko.applyBindings(model);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<button data-bind="click: RefreshBeer">Refresh Beer</button>
<!-- ko if: Beers() -->
<ul>
  <!-- ko foreach: Beers -->
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </li>
  <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Thanks. Although how do I get it to not display any results on page load and display only on click of refreshbeer? My page will not have any results on page load but on click of "search" results will be loaded but if I bind in ajax call return, the view doesn't know about the viewmodel before then

Comment: Well, you do what I did and use the GetBeer().then() which waits for results from the ajax method before executing the contents of the .then() method. That way you know you have data, and instantiate the viewModel after that point. You may need html conditionals like <!-- ko if: Data --><!-- /ko --> to ensure stuff doesn't blow up if there is not actually any data returned.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That helped.